# scala using github repo as a libraryDependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling, scala-gatling

I was facing one error while trying using **RootProject**

I need to use **gatling** snapshot version which is **3.5.0-SNAPSHOT** and to enable this I know two options:-

1. using git clone and then **sbt publishLocal** finally using this jar as an [unmanaged dependency](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Unmanaged+dependencies), This works fine but it is rather more manual work, So I moved to the second option.
2. Using sbt **RootProject**, so let me first explain the project setup:-

> example/Build.sbt

```
lazy val gatling = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/gatling/gatling.git"))

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "example",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
  ).dependsOn(gatling)
```

> example/project/plugins.sbt -> These two were added because it was required while building the project

```
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalafix" % "0.9.21")

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-sbt" %% "io" % "1.4.0"
```

> example/src/main/scala/Main.scala

```
import io.gatling.core.scenario.Simulation

object Main extends App {

  class A extends Simulation

  val a = new A
  println(a.toString)
}
```

So after this executing **sbt run** will result in a successful build.

But the problem starts when I tried to import **gatling-highcharts** in a similar fashion as:-

```
lazy val gatling = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/gatling/gatling.git"))

lazy val gatlingHighCharts = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/gatling/gatling-highcharts.git"))

lazy val root: Project = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "example",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
  ).dependsOn(gatling, gatlingHighCharts)
```

now executing **sbt** will result in an error as:-

```
[error]   not found: C:\Users\user\.ivy2\local\io.gatling\gatling-recorder\3.5.0-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/gatling/gatling-recorder/3.5.0-SNAPSHOT/gatling-recorder-3.5.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[error]   not found: https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/gatling/gatling-recorder/3.5.0-SNAPSHOT/gatling-recorder-3.5.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

And this was because **gatling** is being used via **dependsOn** while actually there is nothing available to do like:-

```
lazy val gatlingHighCharts = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/gatling/gatling-highcharts.git")).dependsOn(gatling)
```

This is not possible **as there is no method named dependsOn inside RootProject class** and I am not able to figure out how to make that work.

Can anyone help me to figure out how can I make that work?

Plus, if somehow exist a way to use github repo jars directly as managed sources instead of unmanaged sources which is something like

```
libraryDependencies += "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.5.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

without using **dependsOn**.

Comment: You might need to add a resolver to be able to fetch snapshot dependencies - https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html

Comment: Have you tried using https://jitpack.io/ ?

Comment: Let me try using jitpack.io

Comment: This is example of a random repo: `libraryDependencies += "com.github.metamx" %% "scala-util" % "master-SNAPSHOT"`. But you can use a release tag as a version, or a commit hash. :)

Comment: @insan-e I think this won't help me. I need something which does this task locally something which is native to sbt or an sbt plugin.

Comment: @PJFanning

I tried but did not get any success.